# delete rows with duplicate Col1, with consideration of deleting the rows with highest value in Col2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that is supposed to have to unique keys. I generate one key (Col2) based on the uniqueness of the other key (Col1). Now, something is happened, I have unique keys in Col2, but some data is repeated in Col1. For instanse, we have

[image]

and I want to automatically delete row with value of DB02, and DB01 remains. Because 02 is bigger than 01 and I want to keep the lowest value (despite the fact that it includes characters).

Could you please help me with the query?

Here is the picture of the query I tried, and the results I did not get. :(

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is similar to what Giorgos Betsos was suggested, but the code should be like this:

```
WITH ToDelete AS (
   SELECT Col2 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1) AS rn
   FROM mytable
)
DELETE FROM ToDelete
WHERE rn > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CTE` to perform `DELETE`:

```
;WITH ToDelete AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col2 ORDER BY Col1) AS rn
   FROM mytable
)
DELETE FROM ToDelete
WHERE rn > 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER` window function is used in order to enumerate records within each `Col2` partition. The record having the lowest `Col1` value is assigned a value of `rn = 1`. All other records have `rn > 1` and are deleted.

Comment: Thanks, could you please the code a little bit. Would it keep the first value?

Comment: This line:

   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col2 ORDER BY Col1) AS rn
   FROM mytable

return a table that all the values is 1, and it returns all of them.
I guess something is wrong

Comment: @yousefyegane No, I explained what values `rn` takes.

Comment: I execute the select query and it returns 62403 records that column rn of all of them is 1, and when I execute count(*) it returns 62403. Meaning all the records is considered as unique. I'm a bit confused about the result. Should it return some rn with values of bigger than 1? I use count and group by, and I can find duplicate record. I also change the place of Col1 and Col2, but the result was not different.

Comment: @yousefyegane It should return values greater than 1 for `Col2` slices having a population greater than one. Can you setup an sqlfiddle demo demonstrating the issue?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36a5e1
For some reason, in the past hour, I couldn't run the code, but the sample data is here, if you could run it please tell me if it works or not.

Comment: @yousefyegane These data do not include records having duplicate `Col2` values.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, change Col1 with Col2. My columns' name are not col1 or col2, and so when I was naming them I typed them in the wrong order.

Comment: @yousefyegane Ok, I did so, and I get several records (actually 9 records) having `rn=2`.

Comment: I'm wondering why I didn't get the same result. Could it be because of Unicode characters in the columns' name? Because I ran several times, and I didn't get any 2. If not I don't know why it's not the same for me.

Comment: I added picture of query I've tried, look at the number of results at the bottom right, and see that it does not change anyway.